# What's the correct way of exposing a support library dependency in an Android library using android-gradle 3?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependency-management, android-gradle-3.0

I develop an android library. The library depends on `appcompat-v7`. My consumers also depend on `appcompat-v7`. How do I most correctly expose my appcompat dependency from the libray when publishing to a maven repository?

What I'm doing now

- Listing the `appcompat-v7` dependency as an `implementation` dependency in the library
- Using [android-maven-publish](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish) to publish POM files which causes the dependency to be listed with Scope "runtime"

Yet with this setup the version preference of the library bleeds onto the consumer. Here is a screenshot from the consumer's project view where the library version is using v27.0.0 and the consumer is set up with 26.1.0:

[image]

v27.0.0 takes presedence over v26.1.0, causing compiler errors (because the Fragment signature has changed).

Is there any way to avoid this by configuring the library different, or *should* this be the result? Am I wrong in assuming that different versions of the appcompat lib should be allowed in the library and in the consuming app? Should I instead publish multiple binaries, each compiled against a different version of the support library to satisfy any given consumer setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to avoid this by configuring the library different,
>   or should this be the result?

Unfortunately, this the expected result. The reason of this issue is that `JVM` doesn't allow to have more than once class with the same package and name.

> Am I wrong in assuming that different versions of the appcompat lib
>   should be allowed in the library and in the consuming app?

As I said, this is a `JVM` restriction.

> Should I instead publish multiple binaries, each compiled against a
>   different version of the support library to satisfy any given consumer
>   setup?

This is the only solution that you have, even do it's very painful.

Comment: I realize you can't have multiple classes with same package and name. My idea was that the client only used their version. That can maybe be solved with ResolutionStrategy? https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html Anyway that means that the library setup is correct?

Comment: No, unfortunately is not possible (at least I don't know how) to tell Gradle to fill your library requirement with their version. Gradle first look for the libraries (including your) and fill the requirements of the libraries , and later found that has multiple versions of the same library and uses the latest version.